# Android: how to send object from BroadcastReceiver to running Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a class that extends `BroadcastReceiver` that reads new sms

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
   // reading sms
   // I want to send the sms text to my main activity
}
```

And have another class in the same app that is my main `Activity`.
So when I receive new sms, I want to send its content to my main Activity that is already running and display it.
How can I do that?
I would be thankful for some code samples :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can suggest you two possibilities

1. send new broadcasts from this  receiver to a new receiver which is registered inside your activity
2. register this receiver inside your activity and reduce the hassle

i guess option two is more suitable

this is how you may register a broadcast receiver inside your activity class:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

public void onResume(){
    filter.addAction("action_string_1");
    filter.addAction("action_string_2");

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

public void onPause(){
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if(action.equals("action_string_1")){
                //do something here
            }
            else if(action.equals("action_string_2")){
                //do somethign here
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: How to register BroadcastReceiver that is inside class?  I now have something like that "<receiver android:name="agent.contactsearcher.SmsReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name=
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>"  But it won't work for the class inside my activity. Another thing is that, when I have 2 separate classes, broadcastreceiver works after shuting down the app, will it work the same when inside the activity?

Comment: no, you dont need to include receiver in your manifest to register a broadcast receiver in your activity class. I've updated my answer to show you how to do this

Comment: Thanks :) You helped me a lot. I've decided to use second BroadcastReceiver, so that I can get sms'es also when my app is closed.